# TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable when using lists and classes

Tags: python, list

Here's a sample of what I'm trying to do

```
class A:
      def xyz(self):
        return n      # Where n is an arbitrary object from a module

class B:
    def abc(self, x): # Where x is an object of class A
      x = x.xyz()     # Where xyz is a method of class A          


if list1[n].abc(list2[k]):  # Where n and k are counters in a loop
  pass
```

There error I keep encountering is `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable` and it occurs in the line `if list1[n].abc(list2[k]):` What does this error mean and how can I resolve it?

Comment: You didn't show how `list1` and `list2` are generated. The error suggests that one (or both) these are not actually lists.

Comment: This is unanswerable, as you have not defined list1 and list2.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you need to understand in order to understand your own question

1) What is a type object

A type object is an object used to describe another object. The type of [1,2,3] is list (lets say we store the type of [1,2,3] in a variable k), the type of this variable k is type. Lets see an example of this in code

```
a = list()
type(a)
<class 'list'>
#As we can see above, the type of a list is 'list'

k = type(a)
type(k)
<class 'type'>
#The type of this list type, is 'type'
```

2) What does it mean to be subscriptable

In order or an object to be subscriptable it must implement the dunder method `__getitem__()`. An item is subscriptable if one can access an element in this object through an index (`your_object[1]`). Examples of subscriptable objects are tuples, lists, string, dict

**So now to answer your question, the reason why this error is occurring is because list1 is a 'type' object, and type objects dont implement the `__getitem__()` method, so you cant perform the  list1[n] operation**